# CSS Transitions: move to the right

Tags: css, html, animation, responsive-design, transition

I have to make a responsive website and as i shrink the browser to a specified size, i want the logo on the left to move to the right so that it is in the centre.

Here's an example of the [transition](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/#.UOqD4ImLIoB) i want to achieve. It is under "2.Animating your transitions" box1

I know that the transition starts on hover but is it possible to activate it when the browser is resized? or any alternative methods at all?

Comment: Why do you want a transition. The only reason a browser resizes is when the screen (viewport) does. What I mean is: nobody is going to "resize" its browser manually, unless you are debugging your own site or watching the magic at other websites to check if the site is responsive. There is no other reason you can think of when a case like yours is happening for the regular user. So why put useless CSS  in your code for that 0.5% who is a designer and wants to check if it is responsive? But, just to support your question. What have you tried already?

Comment: you mean you want this to make the logo's position at the center? why you don't use `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;`

Comment: Lol good point Jelmer, got too carried away since i'm new into responsive design or web design for that matter.

and @gamehelp16, thank you that is helpful too!

Comment: @Jelmer: It could be useful, look at YouTube's new layout when you resize the browser, the video element slides nicely left to sit up against the left side of the browser window. It's a more pleasing effect than just snapping :D

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks It could be useful. In which Use-case? Why would someone resize it's browser window? And if he does, who cares about sliding or snapping? I think you are adding too much CSS which is not that necessary. Ps. why would you like to re-position the logo anyways? Logo on the left is mostly used and research shows that it's the best position because of the F-reading pattern. On the right can be done, but I don't recommend it because you are changing a core design subject of the site. I think you should keep the logo on the same place for a consistent & recognizable User Experience.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks by "you" I meant NLimbu (in the second part), I was replying to you but I got a bit carried away and forgot I had you mentioned in my comment :) I guess you will understand ;)

Comment: @Jelmer I agree with not using transitions but i do need to reposition the logo because on a smaller screen size, the logo is the only element on top and it floats left so the right side has a rather large white space standing oddly :)

Comment: @NLimbu Perhaps that is a nice place to put the 3-bar-icon to for the navigation? ;) I would prefer consistency and thus adding/changing other elements, over re-positioning the logo. But I don't know how it looks like, so I can't tell it for sure :) You know best, I trust your skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a mixture of CSS3 transitions and the @media queries.

```
div
{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

@media all and (min-width: 400px) {
  div
  {
    background-color: #fc3;
    left: 100px;
  }
}
```

What this does is sets up the transitions on the element with relative position but obviously does not fire them (as there's no :hover or other selector) and declares a change in position (`left: 100px;`) when the browser is more than 400px wide. Use `max-width` for a "more than" value.

Obviously you need to change the values to what you need, but this is how it should be done.

http://jsfiddle.net/AvhvD/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would do:

```
1: .logo { display block, width: xxx; margin 0 auto; transition: margin ... }
2: @media (...) { 
  .logo {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I see! that's what i wanted to know. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that you could make a conditional statement in JavaScript and Jquery that would test the following to be true: If the browser window is resized and the size of the browser window is between a range, add a css class. If not remove the css class.

With this new class created, maybe you can make an animation using CSS3. I am not too familiar if this would work, but you could always just revert back to JQuery.

Furthermore, I don't know if transitions can be applied inside of media queries. If so, I am a big proponent and would highly recommend using them.

Hope I could help.